# Text message appears as Chinese Symbols in AT&T

Tags: sms, chinese-language

When I send a text with letters (in English) and Emoji's to a friend from my Galaxy S5,  she receives text that looks all Chinese. She has a Galaxy S7 and we are both on AT&T

Comment: [This blog](http://poetryproseandpoppycock.blogspot.in/2016/10/solved-mark-and-mystery-of-overly.html) says it is an AT&T specific problem and suggests how to go about it. Comments have some alternative ways too

Answer (score 0):

Your network APN settings are messed up somehow. AT&T can assist you with fixing it but I had to change the mine to add admin into the string. It's worth noting it's happening on large messages. It just so happens emojis bloat the send size.